# How do I get the XMLhttp responseText?

Tags: javascript

I am not too familiar with the xmlhttp object, and despite the available documentation, am having trouble getting the `responseText`. Am so close, but would appreciate anyone who could point out why the following does not work; after the `send()` it just dies...:

```
function fetchgenotype() {
    // here's where we use an Ajax function to fetch the allele values without reloading the page.
    // Get the index number of the genotype record to retrieve; retrieve it; populate the alleles.
    var mndx, sndx = 0;
    mndx = $('#marker').val();
    if (Study_selected) {
        sndx = $('#stylabid').val();
    } else {
        sndx = $('#pjtlabid').val();
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            // Recieve the return value, parse and assign to screen form. 
            var allele_stg = "";
            allele_stg = document.getElementById("allele_ary").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            ary = new Array();
            ary = str_getcsv(allele_ary, ',');
            $('#allele_1_1').val() = ary[0];
            $('#allele_1_2').val() = ary[1];
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetchAlleles.php?mndx=" + mndx + "&sndx=" + sndx, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
} // end of fetchgenotype
```

Comment: Is the `onreadystatechange` handler invoked at all? Have you tried a `console.log` before the `if` statement?

Comment: ...FYI, http://jsbeautifier.org is your friend. :)

Comment: @My_Boon: Why would you undo an edit that improved the code formatting? Just because I removed the "last accolade"?

Comment: I undo nothing ... I've just place the last accolade in code block.

Comment: Ummm...  I hate to ask the obvious, but since you appear to be using jQuery (i.e., `$('#allele_1_1').val()`) why not just use `$.get()`? Are you doing it this way to understand the internals of `$.get()`?

Comment: The purpose of this subroutine is to go get some data (genotype) from the database, given two lookup keys (mndx & sndx). The data are then assigned to two variables using javascript, so that the user can then edit them. I fail to see how .get() helps with this task?

Comment: I would like to add: none of these comments helped. My question is simple: how to retrieve the text string returned by .responseText? I can see the value in the debugger, and it is correct; I just don't understand why it does not get assigned to allele_stg? Simple question...because obviously I'm not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what results you're actually getting by changing your `if` statement to:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    // Receive the return value, parse and assign to screen form. 
    var allele_stg = "",
        rText = xmlhttp.responseText;
    /*
     * By assigning xmlhttp.responseText to a seperate variable
     * you can now check to make sure rText contains what you
     * expect to see.
     * 
     * By making the call to getElementById and assigning the
     * innerHTML property in separate statements, you can now
     * check to make sure that getElementById is returning a
     * DOM element, or if it's undefined.
     */
    allele_stg = document.getElementById("allele_ary");
    allele_stg.innerHTML = rText;
    ary = new Array();
    ary = str_getcsv(allele_ary, ',');
    $('#allele_1_1').val() = ary[0];
    $('#allele_1_2').val() = ary[1];
} else {
    console.log('xmlhttp.readyState:' + xmlhttp.readyState);
    console.log('xmlhttp.status:' + xmlhttp.status);
}
```

and then monitoring the console. I suspect you are either not getting a `200` `xmlhttp.status` or `xmlhttp.readyState` is never getting to `4`.

Comment: Actually it does: readystate is 4 and xmlhttp.status is 200, so this branch of logic is where the error occurs. Despite putting in your suggestion for the else clause, I never see anything in the console. Using Firebug to step through the javascript, things go awry with allele_stg = document.getElementById(... where execution gets thrown into deep into core jQuery code, and dies on some branch that says 'undefined'? So I believe the problem lies in how I'm using xmlhttp and innerHTML somehow...

Comment: @rixter: I updated the answer with more debugging steps. Set a breakpoint on the line `allele_stg.innerHTML = rText;` and check the state of the `rText` and `allele_stg` variables. That should at least tell you if `xmlhttp.responseText` and `getElementById` are behaving as expected.